# SAP Homogeneous copy : How do you handle BDLS steps

Tags: sap

Part of SAP Homogeneous copy, we almost always need to perform the BDLS Step.  This can cause a lot of grief cause this step can take few (or a lot) of hours.

How do you manage it ? any tips and trick ?

Comment: Which DB and OS are you running?

Comment: Oracle and DB2 in an AIX environnement

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment, these might help:

- http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1222797
- http://www.sapfans.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=324759
- http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Changing_Logical_System_Name_with_BDLS

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  We have tried, as per most of those link recommend, to create some indexes on particular tables.  It worked fine for our BW environment but, for our ECC environment that is 8TB, it didn't cause the creation of indexes time + bdls time is greater than the original BDLs.